# Multiple parametric equations for planes and lines $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I want to know if you can get different sets of parametric equations for a particular line or plane in $\mathbb R^3$? The reason being I know you can have multiple directional vectors or normal vectors which convey the direction, and these can be scaled, so by this, are there infinitely many possible parametric equations?

Comment: In a word, yes.  Even with _linear_ parameterizations between two points on the iine, for instance, you can choose any two (distinct) real numbers for the values of the parameter at each point.  The _relative_ rates at which the coordinate functions change is dictated by the "direction" of the line, but you can still have $$ x \ = \ x_0 \ + \ at \ , \ y \ = \ y_0 \ + \ bt \ , \ z \ = \ z_0 \ + \ ct \ \ $$ versus  $$ x \ = \ x_0 \ + \ \gamma at \ , \ y \ = \ y_0 \ + \ \gamma bt \ , \ z \ = \ z_0 \ + \ \gamma ct \ \  . $$  And that's just for choosing one specific point for $ \ t \ = \ 0 \ $ .

Comment: (continued)  You can choose other points on the line as the "reference point", but you can also choose from an infinitude of _non_-linear parameterizations (including ones that may re-trace part or all of the line).  It is really a question of what is convenient for the application you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametric equations are never unique. Let's use curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an illustration, for simplicity. Suppose you have parametric equations for some curve:
$$
x = x(t) \quad y = y(t)
$$
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any bijective function. This just means that for each real number $z$, there is a one and only one number $w$ such that $f(w) = z$.

Then the curve
$$
x = x(f(t)) \quad y = y(f(t))
$$
is the same curve as the original. However, if you think of $t$ as time, the point $\big(x(t),y(t)\big)$ is now moving along the curve at a different speed.

Examples of interesting bijections are functions like $f(w) = 3w+7$ or $f(w) = \tanh(w)$.

So, for example, the curve
$$
(x,y) = \big(\tanh(t), 5\tanh(t)\big)
$$
is exactly the same curve as
$$
(x,y) = \big(t, 5t)
$$
They are both the line $y=5x$.